# Batch downloding urls from txt files

Tags: shell-script, wget

I have around 1000 text files. 0001.txt 0002.txt .....to 1000.txt

Every text file have 50 direct image links. how i can batch download these images in there respective folders named 0001, 0002.

Also rename files to maintain downloaded order 1 to 50.

Example links
https://xyz dot com/photos/hdi3bfkdn497ndbdj3.jpg
.
.
.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z $1 ] || egrep -qv '^https?:\/\/[^[:space:]]+' $1; then
  echo "Usage: $0 FILE"
  echo "FILE must be a newline-separated list of URLs."
  exit
fi

INPUT_FILE=$1
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="${INPUT_FILE%.*}"

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

i=1
while read URL; do
  FILENAME="${URL##*/}"
  curl -L $URL > "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${i}_${FILENAME}"
  i=$(($i+1))
done < $INPUT_FILE
```

This script will download all the URLs in a given file into a directory named after the input file with the extension stripped.

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ cat example.txt
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ ./download_from_file example.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9022  100  9022    0     0   477k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  489k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2335  100  2335    0     0   117k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  120k
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ ls example
1_Example.jpg  2_Example.png
```

If you wanted to use this with, say, a thousand text files, you can use a for loop like so:

```
for FILE in $(ls *.txt); do ./download_from_file $FILE; done
```

Comment: @gnubread Hey, Thanks. it work for one txt file. But i don't able to do with multiple files. Right now say 50 files. Can you explain more of that loop thing? sorry noob

Comment: The last part of my answer has an example of how you could call the script on an arbitrary number of files. What part of it is unclear to you?

Comment: https://ibb.co/9VFWxFf $sh script.sh 0001.txt works good, you can see in screenshot, it created folder 0001. I did it for three files. But how do it in batch all these file?

Comment: Have you seen the last line of my answer? The last line of my answer is the way to apply the script to all the files in a directory. Instead of `$ sh script.sh 0001.txt`, the command `$ for FILE in $(ls *.txt); do sh script.sh $FILE; done` would do the trick. If you want more clarification, please make an actual, honest effort to understand and ask clear, specific questions about what confuses you.

Comment: @gnubread Running flawlessly,Is it possible to skip image file size bigger than let say 5 MB?